# Dialer lags when making a call in Yu Yureka running Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, phone-app, micromax-yu-yureka

I upgraded my Yu Yureka to Lollipop using the inbuilt update, and ever since I am seeing a lag while making calls. It takes up to 10 secs to show the call screen after I make the call. I tried clearing the app data, but no luck. Anyone else facing this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: During this 10 secs (before Call screen appears) , do you see a blank screen or the dialer?

Answer (score 1):

this update might solve the bug

Update Size: 130Mb Android version: 5.0.2 Software version: Cyanogen OS 12 (YNG1TAS1K0)

"We are excited to announce a new software update for Yureka which will lead to improved battery performance for YUREKA. (with Cyanogen OS 12 YNG1TAS0W0).

This performance update has been rolled out post feedback from our beta testers community and the roll out process starts today.

Over the next few days ALL users who have official Cyanogen OS 12 YNG1TAS0W0 software on their YUREKA, will receive the update."-YuGod

[Click here for the original post on yu forum](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/incremental-lollipop-update-to-improve-battery-performance-of-yureka.12626/)

Answer (score 0):

Perform a factory reset so that it cleans the phone. Check if the phone lags before installing the extra apps. It won't lag.

Comment: *It won't lag.* -- but if you're certain then why this -- *Check if the phone lags*